# Shortcut for renaming a variable in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

What is a shortcut for renaming a variable in VS 2012?

[image]

Comment: be over the variable and "crlt+r,ctrl+r" that one?

Comment: @ArikRinberg, I would like to hover over the variable, press shortcut and be able to rename it in all occurrences. I would like to set shortcut myself.

Comment: That's set to "ctrl+r,ctrl+r". I'm not sure how to set yourself.

Comment: @ArikRinberg, when I hover over the variable name and press the combination nothing happens and if I try to change the name it will change only in a place over which I am currently hovering. So, the combination `Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R` is not an appropriate one. And the same holds for `Ctrl+R` combination.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxxabwd.aspx   What language are you using?

Comment: @ArikRinberg, C/C++.

Comment: Hmmm, please take a look at the MSDN link i posted. It should help you

Comment: @ArikRinberg, thank you very much for the help. But I do not understand how the link you provided will help me.

Comment: It sends to to a page where it says what the current shortcut is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154126/discussion-between---and-arik-rinberg).